# Save an Image with a new file name [ImageSharp]

Tags: .net-core, imagesharp

I have upgraded my project from .net framework to .net 6 (core). In my project, there are many places where Bitmap is used. I have read in the microsoft documentations that System.Drawing.Common will only support the Windows platform and even after adding the EnableUnixSupport configuration, it will not be supported in net7.So, now I am using ImageSharp.Web. I have the scenario where I save a file as Image (the format is .tiff) then I read from that path as bitmap and save as PNG ( due to some business rule)
Following is the line of code I am trying change:

```
Bitmap.FromFile(completePath).Save(pngPath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

This is the code I have converted into. The only issue is how to save as a new file name as the Tiff file has tiff in the file name.

```
string extension = _GetExtension(img.ContentType);
       


 if (extension == Constants.TiffExtension)
            {
           
            fileName = fileName.Replace(Constants.TiffExtension, "PNG");
           
            using (var outputStream = new FileStream(completePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(completePath);

                image.SaveAsync(outputStream, new PngEncoder()); //how to save new file name?
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: This code leaks for every image. `Image` and `Image<TPixel>` implement `IDisposable`

Comment: so what do u think it should?

Comment: Treat them like you do a stream. Clean up after yourself by either wrapping them in a using statement/declaration or explicitly calling Dispose once finished with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the ImageSharp.Web package while the one I needed was the basic ImageSharp package. Special thanks to @James South for correcting me and @tocsoft for the guidance.

I have fixed it by the following code which is working:

```
 if (extension == Constants.Conversion.TiffExtension)
            {
                using (SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(completePath))
                {
                    string pngPath = completePath.Replace(Constants.Conversion.TiffExtension, Conversion.DefaultExtension);
                    image.Save(pngPath);
                    fileName = fileName.Replace(Constants.Conversion.TiffExtension, Conversion.DefaultExtension);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `image.Save(fileName);` overload to save a image to a file. The file name overload that takes just a path will automatically choose the correct encoder based on the file extension.

Comment: Cannot find any such overload in the version 2.0.1 of imageSharp.web

Comment: That's because  ImageSharp.Web is ASP.NET Core middleware. The extension you are looking for is documented under ImageSharp. https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.ImageExtensions.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_ImageExtensions_Save_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_System_String_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Formats_IImageEncoder_